# Not generating Q classes for parent in query sql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have an entity as shown below:

```
@Table(name = "applicableTax")
@Entity
public class ApplicableTax extends Auditor {

@Id
private Integer id;

}
```

Auditor is in a different package with content.

```
public class Auditor {

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String modifiedBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;

}
```

Now above code is generating QClasses for ApplicableTax.java but it is not generating QClasses for Auditor. Maven build is getting failed in QApplicableTax.java with **cannot not find symbol** QAuditor.

Comment: Look into the documentation of the QueryDSL Maven plugin, maybe you have configured explicit packages? http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.2.BUILD/reference/html/ch03s03.html

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by explicitly disabling generation of parent class Qclasses by using `@QueryExclude`

http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.5.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/annotations/QueryExclude.html

Thanks @Simon for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance in JPA is not automatic. Means you have to declare the inheritance using @MappedSuperclass

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Auditor {

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String modifiedBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;

}
```

Comment: This annotation is present in the auditor already.

Comment: Ok but why do you think there should be a class QAuditor? QAuditor is not an entity

Comment: Is there a way I can ignore the Qclass for auditor class ?

Comment: I don't know why it's requesting this class. Can you share a reproducible example?